# Hypothesis testing- lognormal distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, lognormal-distribution

I have a conditional mean and standard error for a parameter log-normally distributed.

I want to test whether the mean of the distribution is significantly different from an alternate estimate of 0.8. My first reaction is to do a standard t-test but I see this is no good.

my estimates for the mean and standard deviation (derived from probit model) are

m   .7453726   (.0061561)

se  .2242749   (.0073073)

Comment: "test whether the mean is significant" doesn't mean anything. Without using statistical jargon terms can you explain in plain words what it is you want to find out about the mean? (Alternatively, can you be more statistically formal and specify a null hypothesis, and an alternative if it's anything but negation of a point null?) Also, how do you know the distribution of the variable?

Comment: fixed it up a bit. the distribution of the parameter is known because a probit model containing natural logs was used.

Comment: How is the "alternate estimate" obtained? Is it based on data? (the same data or different data? and how?)

Comment: the alternate estimate is just another academics estimate. exogenous to the model.

Comment: Good on you for having a real null hypothesis that isn't just zero for the heck of it. But what's wrong with the t test in your case?

Comment: @ssdecontrol the distribution is log normal. I don't think a t-test works because the distribution isn't normal or symmetric.

Comment: How big is your sample? Do you know about the central limit theorem?

Comment: Jamzy "another academics estimate" *doesn't* give the information required. Please address the specifics I asked about. Is it based on *data*?

Comment: @ssdecontrol roughly 4k. I don't think the central limit theorem holds here because it doesn't involve an arithmetic mean.

Comment: @Glen_b the 0.8 is is a pretty arbitrary estimate. Not directly based on data.

Comment: Okay. It's not clear how to properly deal with the uncertainty in "an arbitrary estimate" that's not directly based on data. One can treat it as a fixed constant, of course, as if it weren't based on finite data, but that's pretty much a fudge.

Comment: Are those estimates of the mean and sd of the lognormal or are they estimates of the parameters of the lognormal? What sample size do you have?

Comment: @Glen_b they are estimates of the parameters. I'll add more information this evening, including stata code.

Comment: Stata code won't help me (maybe it will help others) -- but feel free to add information.

Comment: If those are estimates of the parameters, I am sure you cannot mean to test that the mean of the lognormal is 0.8 (it looks to me like the mean of the lognormal is probably above 2). Do you mean to test whether the $\mu$ parameter differs from 0.8?

Comment: @Glen_b yep, that what I want to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After clarifications in comments, it seems that the aim is to test $H_0:\mu=0.8$ against (I presume) a two sided alternative.

It seems like we have:

- a parameter estimate, $\hat{\mu}$
- an estimate of its standard error

from fitting a model by maximum likelihood (among some other quantities).

The obvious thing to do is to assume $n$ is large enough that an asymptotic test will be sufficiently accurate and do a [Wald test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald_test#Test_on_a_single_parameter).

Asymptotically under the null, $W=\frac{\hat{\mu}-\mu_0}{\hat{\sigma}_\hat{\mu}}\sim N(0,1)$, where $\hat{\sigma}_\hat{\mu}$ is the estimated *standard error of the estimate of* $\mu$, so if $|W|\geq Z_{1-\alpha/2}$, the null would be rejected.

(alternatively but equivalently, the square of that statistic could be compared to the $1-\alpha$ quantile of a $\chi^2_1$)